# an issue updating Android SDK Tools rev 19 to rev 20 using windows 7- 64bit

Tags: android, sdk

I have an issue updating the android SDK tools rev 19 to rev 20 & Android SDK Platform-tool rev 11 to rev 12.

I checked the SDK manager log and it displayed the below error:

> File not found: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\temp\platform-tools_r12-windows.zip (Access is denied)
>
> Skipping 'Android SDK Tools, revision 20'; it depends on 'Android SDK Platform-tools, revision 12' which was not installed.
>
> Done. Nothing was installed.

Answer (score 39):

Have you tried running the SDK Manager "as administrator" ?

Following steps to run SDK manager as administrator on windows 7

- Right Click SDK Manager
- Select Run As Administrator
- Click the YES button (if asked for)

Comment: I did, but did not work so I Un-installed it to re-installed the most updated ADT and its working now :)

Comment: I must have tried updating a dozen times with no success and couldn't figure out what to do.  How silly of me not to think of this, and how brilliant of you!

Comment: Running as Admin worked for me.  I originally encountered this problem because I tried to update the SDK manager via Eclipse.  Why is that?  Is it because I didn't run Eclipse as an Admin?  Or some kind of design flaw in the Android SDK manager?

Comment: @jfritz42 : I am not sure why is that, but you can fix "Eclipse access denied" by giving right to your user (Via "Android SDK main Folder properties (on right click)" -> security and then edit the rights).

Answer (score 5):

This method works only for Windows 7 x64 :

1. Right click on `SDK.exe`
2. Click Properties
3. Select Compatibility
4. Check on `Run This Program in Compatibility mod`e for Windows XP SP3.
5. `Run this Program as Administrator`.
6. Apply & Ok

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

- Dowload zip file from [this link](http://dl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools_r12-windows.zip).
- Navigate to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\temp\` and extract dowloaded file to this folder
- It will rewrite your platform tools folder.
- Download SDK tools revision 20 from [here](http://dl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r20-windows.zip) and add it to `temp` folder.

That's it. It works for me.

Answer (score 2):

All you have to do is:

1. Right click on the `SDK.exe` file.
2. Select `trouble shoot compatibilty`.
3. Do not select the problem you don't have.
4. You are ready to go.

Worked for me, hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

dont run your eclipse short cut as admin ..run the actual exe as admin